# Clojure - Unknown number of arguments in a function

Tags: clojure

I have a function

```
(defn x [w]
  (let [[w1 w2 w3] w]
    (println w1)
    (println w2)
    (println w3)))
```

If I call the function

```
(x [[1 1] [2 2] [3 3]])
=> [1 1]
   [2 2]
   [3 3]
```

which is what I expect

Is there a way to generalise this? In this case I knew that `w` was a vector containing 3 vectors so I know to have `[w1 w2 w3]` If `w` was then a vector of 4 vectors, the last vector would not be set to anything

What I want is where `w` is a vector of n vectors and then in the `let` of the function set them to `[w1 w2 w3 ... wn]`? (note doesn't necessarily have to be w1, w2, ... wn)

The println are just there for debugging so not that important for the function

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: How are you going to refer to `w1`, `w2` etc if you don't know how many there are? It sounds like you should process the incoming sequence instead of destructuring it.

Comment: `map`, `reduce`, `transduce`, `filter` are but a few collection processing functions available that don't need hard coded associations to the collection elements. You will grow to love these...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(defn x [ws]
  (dorun (map println ws)))
```

For example,

```
(x [[1 1] [2 2] [3 3]])
[1 1]
[2 2]
[3 3]
=> nil
```

- The `map` applies `println` to each of the `ws` in turn, returning
  the `nil` results as a sequence, *on demand* (lazily).
- The `dorun` demands the whole sequence, discarding it as it goes,
  returning `nil`.

---

If you want to see the sequence, replace `dorun` with `doall`:

```
(defn x [ws]
  (doall (map println ws)))

=> (x [[1 1] [2 2] [3 3]])
[1 1]
[2 2]
[3 3]
=> (nil nil nil)
```

---

A more concise alternative  to the former is

```
(defn x [ws]
  (doseq [w ws] (println w)))
```

... and to the latter is

```
(defn x [ws]
  (for [w ws] (println w)))
```

Comment: I realize you're using `println` for illustrative purposes only, but in case anyone reading thinks `(doall (map println ws))` is a good idea for general use, I wanted to comment to discourage its use.  For side-effecting processing of a collection where you don't care about the result, the modern clojure best practice is `run!`:   `(run! println coll)`  `(doall (map...` is wrong probably 80% of the time (discounting REPL use).  Again, your answer uses `println` only as an example, so this isn't a comment about your answer itself, just for general info for anyone reading. Upvoted your answer.

Comment: @Josh Thanks, Josh. I didn't know about `run!`. As for `println`, I just followed what OP did. My clumsy code is to tease out the sequence processing (the real point of the question, I suspect) from the side-effect issue.